# Verifying a Homomorphism

Tags: group-theory

I want to show that the following application is a homomorphism:

$f: D_{2n} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(r^i) =O$ and $f(sr^i) =1$

Here is my plan:

Let $g_1, g_2 \in D_2n$

- First step: If $f(g_1)f(g_2) = 1$ then $g_1=sr^i$, $g_2= sr^j$ I need to show that $g_1g_2 = sr^k$
- Second step: If $f(g_1)f(g_2) = 0$ then $g_1=r^i$, $g_2= sr^j$ or vice versa or $g_1 = r^i$ and $g_2 = r^j$ I need to show that $g_1g_2 = r^k$

**First step**

I am already encountering a problem, indeed, $g_1g_2 = sr^isr^j=s^2r^{i+jmod(n)} = r^{i+jmod(n)}$.  Therefore $f(g_1)f(g_2)\neq f(g_1g_2) $

Where have I made a mistake?

Or does it not define a homomorphism?

Showing the second step is easy but I'm having trouble with the first one

Comment: Note that $s^2=1$

Comment: The first step is a mistake. If $g_1 = sr$ and $g_2 = sr$, then $g_1g_2$ is a rotation, not symmetry.

Comment: @Santiago That is precisely the problem

Comment: The group operation on $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is addition (modulo $2$), not multiplication. So $f(g_1) + f(g_2) = 1 \iff f(g_1) \neq f(g_2)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank You, indeed now it defines a homomorphism